# python - Splitting a list of integers into list of digits

Tags: python, list

I have a list which contains 8-digit integers, where each integer represents a flag. e.g:

```
qc = [11221427, 23414732, 144443277,...]
```

I want to create 8 new variables where first variable is the first digit of all the numbers and so on. e.g:

```
qc1 = [1,2,1]
qc2 = [1,3,4]
```

I am able to calculate it using the following code:

```
qc_str = [str(e) for e in qc]

k,l = 0,0

for item in qc_str:
    qc1[k] = int(qc_str[k][l])
    qc2[k] = int(qc_str[k][l+1])
    qc3[k] = int(qc_str[k][l+2])
    qc4[k] = int(qc_str[k][l+3])
    qc5[k] = int(qc_str[k][l+4])
    qc6[k] = int(qc_str[k][l+5])
    qc7[k] = int(qc_str[k][l+6])
    qc8[k] = int(qc_str[k][l+7])

    k += 1
```

It takes a lot of time for running on 100,000 rows. Is there a better or faster way of doing it. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is one way:

```
qc = [11221427, 23414732, 144443277]

lst = [list(map(int, i)) for i in zip(*map(str, qc))]

# [[1, 2, 1],
#  [1, 3, 4],
#  [2, 4, 4],
#  [2, 1, 4],
#  [1, 4, 4],
#  [4, 7, 3],
#  [2, 3, 2],
#  [7, 2, 7]]
```

If you really need these as separate variables, either use `lst[idx]` or a dictionary `{i: j for i, j in enumerate(lst, 1)}`.

Comment: oh, I love that `zip(*seq)` construct!

Answer (score 2):

If by faster you meant a lower processing time, you should note that the str() and int() casts are computationally pretty expensive.

You should consider using integer division and modulus to extract the single digits:

`k-th digit (from the left) = number / 10^(k-1) % 10`

Here some quick dirty code I used to confirm my hypothesis.

```
    import time

    l = [x for x in range(1000000,9999999)]
    l2 = []
    l3 = []

    start = time.time()
    for x in l:
        a = str(x)
        l2.append(int(a[-2]))

    stop = time.time()
    print ("Elasped time: ", stop-start)

    start = time.time()
    for x in l:
        l3.append(x//10 % 10)

    stop = time.time()

    print("Elapsed time: ", stop-start)
```

Basically I compare the timings between doing a str() and an int() and extracting the digits using integer division to extract the 2nd digits.

I get the following output:

```
13.855608940124512
5.115100622177124
```

That's a 2.5x performance boost.